# How to capture city name

Tags: geolocation, geocoding, geofencing

Is there an accurate way to capture the city/town/village of a user without having them mention it.The gps co ordinates only give you the distance from a specific spot.

Answer (score 0):

According you have a database (from geoname or whatever open or private sources you can easily find on internet) or use an api (like [api.geoname.org](http://api.geonames.org/)), you can locate in which village is the coordinate and then find the town, then the country ...